# sending a list of checked boxes from view to controller in play framework java

Tags: java, list, model-view-controller, checkbox, playframework

I have a view with the checkboxes

```
 @for((jc)<-jobcategoryList) {

           <input type="checkbox" name="jobcategory.id" value="@jc.id">@jc.name<br>
                                }
```

I just want to send this list of checked checkboxes to my controller.But on doing this

```
public class JobAdController extends Controller {
    public static Result save() {


            Form<Jobads> jobadsFormData = jobadsForm.bindFromRequest();



            if (jobadsFormData.hasErrors()) {

          System.out.println("Error in form");
                 return badRequest();


            } else {

            Jobads jads= jobadsFormData.get();
            List<Jobcategories> jadsList= jads.getJobcategory();

            System.out.print("\nLength is:"+jadsList.size());// always prints Length is:0





          }}
}
```

where Jobads and Jobcategory are my models.

My Jabads.java model

```
public class Jobads extends Model {


    @ManyToMany

    private List<Jobcategories> jobcategories;
}
```

**My problem is that whenever i  submit my view form  with the checkboxes(given above).My console prints Length is:0**

When i tried to change my view to

```
@for((jc,index)<-jobcategoryList.zipWithIndex) {

               <input type="checkbox" name="jobcategory[index]" value="@jc">@jc.name<br>
                                    }
```

and submit my form the controller an [[NumberFormatException: For input string: "index"]] is generated on the first line of controller.

How can I send this checked boxes to my controller.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
@for(jc <- jobcategoryList) {
    <input type="checkbox" name="jobcategories[]" value="@jc.id">@jc.name<br>
}
```

or

```
@for((jc,index) <- jobcategoryList.zipWithIndex) {
    <input type="checkbox" name="jobcategories[@index]" value="@jc.id">@jc.name<br>
}
```

and in your form class:

```
public List<Long> jobcategories;
```

Comment: giving  `[IllegalStateException: No value]` at line `Jobads jads= jobadsFormData.get();`

Comment: I can't guess what's wrong with your own code, use debugger to find the bug

Comment: biesior my jobcategory variable is List<Jobcategory> type (see my update) above so when i used `<input type="checkbox" name="jobcategory.id" value="@jc.id">@jc.name<br>` there was no exception but the list length is still zero.